# Merge sort in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working through intro to algorithms and translating the pseudocode into a variety of languages for practice.

I am stuck on javascript.  I cannot figure out why my merge function is failing and duplicating inputs.  Do you know why?

Thank you

```
function mergesort(a){
    if (a.length <=1) {
        return a;
        }
    mid = Math.round((a.length/2));
    left = a.slice(0, mid);
    right = a.slice(mid);
    console.log(left,right);
    return merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right));
}

function merge(left, right) {
    sorted = [];
    console.log(sorted,left, right, left[0], right[0]);
    while (left && left.length >0 && right && right.length >0){
        if (left[0] <= right[0]) {
            sorted.push(left.shift());
            console.log("left", left, right);
        }
        else {
            sorted.push(right.shift());
            console.log("left", left, right);
        }
    }
    return sorted.concat(left,right);
}


a = [234,526,6,3,2,5];
mergesort(a);
```

Comment: You realize that you are creating a global `sorted` variable, right?

Comment: Also all the variables in `mergesort` are global. Global variables and recursion don't generally mix.

Comment: Use `var sorted` to prevent creating globals. All variables are global by default in JS if you omit the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm looks fine, the big **problem is you are creating global variables**. When you create a variable without using `var` keyword, that variable will become a global variable.

In your case, the first time you are creating a global variable and then on the successive recursive calls, you are not creating new variables, but reassigning to the the same global variables. To fix this problem, simply prefix the variable declarations with `var`, like this

```
var mid = Math.round((a.length/2));
var left = a.slice(0, mid);
var right = a.slice(mid);
...
...
...
var sorted = [];
```

With that change, the result becomes

```
[ 2, 3, 5, 6, 234, 526 ]
```